# How to create .exe using pyinstaller for a multipage streamlit application

Tags: python, pyinstaller, streamlit

I am trying to create an .exe file for my streamlit multipage app so that user can run this app on their desktop without worrying about python and other dependences.

i am able to run single page streamlit app as an .exe following the step mentioned in this repo

**https://github.com/jvcss/PyInstallerStreamlit/tree/master**

Additional what I want is if I wanted to add pages under the folder pages (additional streamlit pages like page_1.py, page_2.py) along with my app.py then all 3 pages should be available in the web browser.(app.py, page_1.py,page_2.py).

Right now only app.py is getting displayed and not page_1 and page_2.

Anyone has tried out anything similar?

I am able to create .exe file for  single streamlit page app and it is running fine. When trying to apply for multi page i am not able to see other pages in my web browser.